# Broken markup on some questions (but the preview works)

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

In at least one questions ( [How to compute molecular formula?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/372/how-to-compute-molecular-formula)) there is broken formatting, but only in the posted form. The preview view (if one were to try and edit it) shows what I believe is the correct output.

Text for the line in question:

> `WCl$_{6}$, WCl$_{14}$, WCl$_{18}$, and WCl$_{21}$.`

How it is displayed on the site:

[image]

How it is previewed:

[image]

This appears to be a bug.

Comment: Please test stuff here: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112/22

Comment: Does it show up as a bug for you as well?

Comment: Yep.. Found other strange stuff  as well. I'll investigate later.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4595462#4595462

Comment: This definitely looks like the difference between the preview and server back-end code.  See [this reply](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3955/7798) for more details about the code changes.  I'm wondering if the fix was only applied to the math.stackexchange.com site?

Comment: @DavideCervone: Fortunately, the SE mods hang around beta sites, so we may not have to wait too long for an answer.

Comment: Has anyone tested this *on* any other SE sites? So far as I know, the fix @Manis links to wasn't specific to Math.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MathJax developer [Davide Cervone](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/219/davide-cervone) has created an improved parser for better separation of $\LaTeX$ and Markdown (thanks a lot!). We've tested it on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for a while, and since it has been working great, I have now enabled it everywhere. The bug you found is one of the issues that this new parser solves, so this shouldn't happen again.