# Clumsy view of well-formatted questions: What to do?

Tags: discussion, bug, mathjax

Before you ask, I *did* see [this](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/broken-markup-on-some-questions-but-the-preview-works). No problems should be there now, right? However, I ran into wierd (not to mention funny, I laughed for about 5 minutes non-stop) questions; take a look at the pic:
[image: HAHAHA]

The former strange-looking question is edited by ManishEarth! Correct and thorough formatting was applied, and in the [main page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4289/does-resonance-apply-to-no2) of the question you see no problems. But searches and question lists seem to have an algorithm that misinterprets the dollar signs:

> ...now I am a little bit confused since I cannot figure out the resonance structure for...

Before and after the phrase above we have dollar signs that were used for the formatting of $\ce{NO2^-}$ and $\ce{NO2+}$. (Actually, I think this "and" between the formatted text would've looked funny too, but it's in three dots).

So, what should we do about these questions? We can't leave them like that, can we?!

Comment: The good part is... these apparitions are not few! And they seems to be raising their ugly head in searches only.

Comment: I'll leave this here as a bug and perhaps one of the developers will comment on it.  I would imagine that it parses Mathjax on the whole page instead of just the question snippets (i.e., an odd number of dollar signs on the entire search page messes the whole thing up). but I will defer to the JavaScript able for a better answer.

Comment: It is definitely a kind of bug for the search page, where maths gets interpreted wrong. The questions are fine, it's just that the excerpt is messy. Maybe it's worthwhile asking this on meta.se; I was only able to find something almost similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217389/260760

Comment: @Martin the question you addressed is about the same issue, however with no answer. If things don't get solved here I'll ask it at meta.SE.

Comment: @Martin I just posted the question at meta.SE.

Comment: @Martin. The devs read questions tagged [tag:bug] on all meta sites. Unless you know or have good reason to believe that the bug in question affects all SE sites, there's no good reason to post to Meta SE. (And even if you do think it applies to all SE sites, there's no *need* to post to Meta SE.)

Comment: @TRiG, WE HAVE OUR OWN REASONS SARGENT. :D

Comment: I think he forgot to put the $ sign in the end.